# Trim Part of a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string in a variable like this:

```
$var = "This is a banana (fruit)";
```

How do I trim / get the part 'fruit' only? (i.e., data inside braces whatever it is).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $sentence = "This is a banana (fruit)";
  $a = stripos($sentence,"(");
  $b = stripos($sentence,")");
  echo substr($sentence, $a, $b);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_rpelace function:

```
<?php 
$str = "This is a banana (fruit)";
echo preg_replace('/.*\((.*)\).*/','$1',$str);
?>
```